# Android Test Instrumentation Runner Arguments set during execution phase

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am trying to create gradle tasks to run only a sub set of tests based on annotations, which is detailed [in the gradle dsl](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig:testInstrumentationRunnerArguments).  I am trying to set the `testInstrumentationRunnerArguments` during the gradle execution phase.  While I am successfully setting the arguments it doesn't appear to actually do any filtering.

We do have the tests located in a different source set path but we have added them to the default `androidTest` source set. The tests all run  they are simply not filtered.

My questions then become: Can the test arguments be dynamically set during the execution phase of gradle or do they need to be set in the configuration phase?  If they can be set during execution can any one point out why the below gradle wont work?

Here is my test.gradle which is applied after the android library configuration closure.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2018 company. All rights reserved.
 */

ext {
    integrationTest = false
    networkIntegrationTest = false
}

android.sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        java {
            // add our custom test source sets so android studio gives us good tooling
            srcDirs += './src/integrationNetworkTest/java'
            srcDirs += './src/integrationTest/java'
        }
        res {
            srcDirs += './src/integrationNetworkTest/res'
            srcDirs += './src/integrationTest/res'
        }
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    def name = task.name.toLowerCase()
    if(name.contains('connectedcheck') || task.name.matches("connected([a-zA-Z]?)+AndroidTest")) {
        task.doFirst {
            if(!integrationTest && !networkIntegrationTest) {
                android.productFlavors.each {
                    it.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.put('notAnnotation',
                    'com.company.android.infrastructure.test.IntegrationTest,com.company.android.infrastructure.test.IntegrationNetworkTest')
                }
            }
            else {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
                if(integrationTest && networkIntegrationTest) {
                    sb.append('com.company.android.infrastructure.test.IntegrationTest')
                    sb.append(',')
                    sb.append('com.company.android.infrastructure.test.IntegrationNetworkTest')
                }
                else if (integrationTest) {
                    sb.append('com.company.android.infrastructure.test.IntegrationTest')
                }
                else if (networkIntegrationTest) {
                    sb.append('com.company.android.infrastructure.test.IntegrationNetworkTest')
                }
                if(integrationTest || networkIntegrationTest) {
                    android.productFlavors.each {
                        it.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.put('annotation', sb.toString())
                    }
                }
            }

            android.productFlavors.each {
                println "${it.name} Test Annotations: ${it.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments}"
            }
        }
    }
}
project.afterEvaluate {
    android.libraryVariants.each { variant ->
        tasks.create("${variant.name}IntegrationTest") {
            group 'company'
            description 'Run company Integration tests with only network requests mocked'
            finalizedBy "connected${variant.name.capitalize()}AndroidTest"
            doLast {
                integrationTest = true
            }
        }

        tasks.create("${variant.name}IntegrationNetworkTest") {
            group 'company'
            description 'Run company Integration tests with real network requests'
            finalizedBy "connected${variant.name.capitalize()}AndroidTest"
            doLast {
                networkIntegrationTest = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle: 4.1

Android Plugin: 3.0.1

*Edit: * I think its a bug: [Android Bug Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79996758)